# Computed Property - How to use only on main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, avfoundation

I am trying to use an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to capture video, however when I run my application, the main thread checker causes the crash.

At what point must the code be run on the main thread - I am assuming this will resolve the issue I am having. Several attempts have been made using `DispatchQueue.main.async({})` but to no avail.

Error Occurring:

> Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread:

Original:

```
    var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {

    let previewlayer = layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

    switch gravity {
      case .resize:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
      case .resizeAspect:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
      case .resizeAspectFill:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    }
    return previewlayer
   }
```

Attempted Fix:

```
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {

  getVideoPreviewLayer { (previewLayer) in
    return previewLayer
  }
}

func getVideoPreviewLayer( completion: @escaping (AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) -> ()) {

  DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self ] in

    let previewlayer = self.layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

    switch self.gravity {
    case .resize:
      previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
    case .resizeAspect:
      previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    case .resizeAspectFill:
      previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    }

    completion(previewlayer)
  }
}
```

---

Original
[image]
Attempted Fix
[image]

Comment: Try using the DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: () -> Void>) instead.

Comment: The only reason why I haven't set an answer is that, even though DispatchQueue.main.async or sync, must be used. I've Used it on every instance of 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' where the main thread catcher is pausing the app and the error has not yet been dismissed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution to ensure you only get the layer on the main queue no matter which queue is used to access `videoPreviewLayer`:

```
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    let previewlayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = {
        if Thread.current.isMainThread {
            return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                return layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
            }
        }
    }()

    switch gravity {
    case .resize:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
    case .resizeAspect:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    case .resizeAspectFill:
        previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    }
    return previewlayer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `DispatchQueue.main.sync` because you want to wait for the response (you want to return the resulting value).  Using async would cause your code to continue before you have a value.

You also don't need to deal with a separate function.

Here is a simple fix that should work:

```
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer {
    let capturedLayer = DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        previewlayer = layer as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

        switch gravity {
            case .resize:
                previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
            case .resizeAspect:
                previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
            case .resizeAspectFill:
                previewlayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        }
        return previewlayer
    }
    return capturedLayer
}
```

However, you might run into problems trying to do something with the layer returned from this function because you will be off the main thread.  It's probably a good idea to move to the main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.sync` somewhere else (somewhere in the context that gets the videoPreviewLayer variable).

Comment: This will cause a deadlock if `videoPreviewLayer` is accessed from the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, your attempted fix will not compile, since it expects a return value, meanwhile you're wrapping this getter in an asynchronous dispatch.

The point here is not how you define the getter, but how you use it. The *original* part of your code is completely fine, as long as you remember that this is an UI-related API and you have to call it only from the main thread. So, instead of messing around with this part of your code, you should rather wrap the call to `videoPreviewLayer` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call, something like that:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let _ = _something_.videoPreviewLayer
}
```